# Python on Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio

When I installed Visual Studio 2015 I also installed PTVS (Python Tools for Visual Studio) version 2.2.4; But after I installed it, autocomplete won't work for my Python code. I have installed an interpreter (CPython 3.5) and that still doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you configured it correctly, it would still take some time for IntelliSense to finish scrapping and analysing your python libraries.